# Cannot clear the text of FreeTextBox control

Tags: c#, asp.net, freetextbox

I have a FreeTextBox control in my aspx page.

First, the client types the text into the FreeTextBox and click button `Save` to write the text into Database (sql server 2008).

Then, in Edit function, the text is loaded from Database into FreeTextBox again for Editing.

After Editing, client clicks `OK` to write the new text into Database but the new text isn't allowed be null or empty.

Take a look at my simple code:

```
public void btn_OK()
{
     if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(FTB.Text))
         Labelerror.Text="The text cannot be null or empty.";

      else
      {
        ...write new text into Database...
       }

}
```

Building: when I clear the old text and click OK, the program passes the `if` statement and does the codes inside `else` statement (write new text into Database).

Try to debug, I clear the old text and let the FreeTextBox empty but the `FTB.Text= "<p class=\"MsoNormal\"><br></p>"`

Where is the `<p class=\"MsoNormal\"><br></p>`from???

As recommended, I use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` to decode that html tag:

```
string text= HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(FTB.Text);
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
```

But nothing change: `text= "<p class=\"MsoNormal\"><br></p>"`

Help!!! How can I remove that html tag to check if the FreeTextbox is null or empty.

Comment: Perhaps that is a default p-tag from the control itself?

Comment: @Abbas no, I've inserted text form FreeTextbox for many time then I check the text in Database, some of them dont have p-tag

Comment: I went to their website where you can demo the FTB. If you leave it empty and press save, a default p-tag is saved, this is not the case when you have typed text in the FTB (depending on text-markup).

Comment: poor me, I dont have any idea to solve this problem.